# Long Pointer to Constant Wide String, what's the function of the Long here?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, long-integer

When you have a LPCWSTR, why is it a Long Pointer?  There's no Long in it's definition, as far as I know.

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Long' is a leftover from Windows-16-bit. In the old days, on DOS and Windows 3.x, most apps were 16 bits and had 16-bit pointers. 32-bit pointers were 'long' and had to be specially declared, and used (in some DOS cases) selectors and not the flat address space.

Answer (score 1):

On 32-bit or greater machines, a long pointer is the same as any other pointer.  The difference appears on machines with smaller native word sizes where you might have a 16-bit pointer and a 32-bit pointer type, for example.  Usually they are called [`near` and `far` pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model).